# C++ Loop recieves integers until given Q

Tags: c++, loops, int

The loop should receive inputs until q or Q is given. Although the loop expects an integer and a char q or Q breaks the loop and is not recognized. How can I allow the loop to recognize q or Q to break the loop?

```
int ReadInput;      // Remembers input elements given
string ReadInputString = to_string(ReadInput); // String version of the ReadInput 

        do
        {
            bool NoErrors = true;   // Make sure there were no errors while reading input

            std::cout << "Enter the next element (Enter 'q' to stop): "; // Prompt user for input
            cin >> ReadInput;

            if (ReadInputString == quit || ReadInputString == Quit) // Enter Q or q to quit
            {
                break;
            }

            /* Validation */
            if (cin.fail()) 
            {
                /* Pass by the bad input */
                NoErrors = false; // Note there was a problem
                cin.clear(); // Clear the bad input
                cin.ignore(); // Ignore the bad input
                std::cout << "Invalid number" << endl; // Error message
            }

            /* Add the input to the list (if there were no problems) */
            if (NoErrors)
            {
                NumbersList.push_back(ReadInput); // Put the given number onto the end of the list
            }

        } while (ReadInput >= 0);
```

Comment: `quit` and `Quit` were what again?

Comment: You also have some more completely nonsensical stuff in your code:: `cin >> ReadInput;` reads an `int` value, but you want to compare that to `"q"` or `"Q"`.

Comment: That's pretty different from what you're asking the user to input.

Comment: string quit = "q"; 
string Quit = "Q";

Comment: You're still poking around in darkness and mist.

Answer (score -1):

it doesnt matter where you are storing the numbers finally. you were taking input in integer variable and were expecting a char to be stored there. so just take a char there, check if it contains a digit, if yes, convert it to num and proceed, if it is a char check it is q or Q and break if yes

```
int ReadInput;

char temp;

string ReadInputString = to_string(ReadInput); // String version of the ReadInput 

        do
        {
            bool NoErrors = true;   // Make sure there were no errors while reading input

            std::cout << "Enter the next element (Enter 'q' to stop): "; // Prompt user for input

            cin >> temp;                        //store input as char 
            if (isdigit(temp))                  //check input is number or not
                ReadInput = temp;               //convert input to num if true
            else if (temp == 'q' | temp == 'Q') //if not number check for q or Q
                break;                          //break if q

            if (ReadInputString == quit || ReadInputString == Quit) // Enter Q or q to quit
            {
                break;
            }

            /* Validation */
            if (cin.fail()) 
            {
                /* Pass by the bad input */
                NoErrors = false; // Note there was a problem
                cin.clear(); // Clear the bad input
                cin.ignore(); // Ignore the bad input
                std::cout << "Invalid number" << endl; // Error message
            }

            /* Add the input to the list (if there were no problems) */
            if (NoErrors)
            {
                NumbersList.push_back(ReadInput); // Put the given number onto the end of the list
            }

        } while (ReadInput >= 0);
```

Comment: There are reasons why your are discouraged to post code only answers! All that could be solved way more easily reading in a `std::string` value in 1st place!

Comment: proper comments are added to make the changes fully understandable

Comment: They are stored in a vetor<int> NumbersList.